# Why does not VS2010 oracle query window show output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oracle

I have following statements in Oracle query window in VS2010, 
It does not show output!, event the statement dbms_output.put_line('Hello') shows nothing;
How do I enable the output ?

```
 set serveroutput on;
    clear;
    declare c sys_refcursor;
      r pkgPriceWorx.recPriceListCustomers;
      comno varchar2(3);
      cpls number;
      o varchar(3000);
    disc number;
    begin
    --select * from ftPriceListCutomers('020','221');
     comno:='020';
    cpls:=221;
       dbms_output.put_line('helllo');
      --c:=pkgPriceWorx.ftPriceListCustomers(comno,cpls);
      --loop
        -- fetch c into r;
         --dbms_output.put_line(r.cuno);
         dbms_output.put_line('helllo');
         --exit when c%notfound;
      --end loop;
      disc:=23.2;
      pkgPriceWorx.prUpdateOrInsertDiscount('020','221','000051','1AA00','20-mar-1999',disc,o );

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set serveroutput on;` and `clear;` are sqlplus commands, not plsql so they will probably won't work in other environments.
I don't know if you can write messages to some standard output this way, but if you want to debug your plsql from vs2010, you can use this tutorial:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/debugging/Debugging.htm

or use [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm) for logging to a file.